# Pattern matching generic case classes for compiler

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, pattern-matching

I have created a rather simple abstract language with Scala. As of now I'm attempting to implement type errors with the usage of scalas generic case classes but have reached a mental block of understanding. - Here's my current (not working) solution:

```
sealed abstract class TypedExpr[T]
case class CstI(value: Int) extends TypedExpr[Int]
case class Add(e1: TypedExpr[Int], e2: TypedExpr[Int]) extends TypedExpr[Int]
case class Times(e1: TypedExpr[Int], e2: TypedExpr[Int]) extends TypedExpr[Int]
case class LessThanEq(e1: TypedExpr[Int], e2: TypedExpr[Int]) extends TypedExpr[Boolean]
case class IfThenElse[T](cond: TypedExpr[Boolean], e1: TypedExpr[T], e2: TypedExpr[T]) extends TypedExpr[T]

object Language {

  def eval[T](e: TypedExpr[T]): T = e match {
    case CstI(n) => n
    case Add(e1, e2) => eval(e1) + eval(e2)
    case Times(e1, e2) => eval(e1) * eval(e2)
    case LessThanEq(e1, e2) => eval(e1) <= eval(e2)
    case IfThenElse(cond, e1, e2) => if (eval(cond)) eval(e1) else eval(e2)
  }
}
```

As of now I'm getting type errors due to fx. CstI not being of type T.

Now what grinds my gears is that this scenario would never occur. What is an elegant solution to this? Preferably with usage of case classes and generic types.

Comment: What is your `scala` version? Works fine for me at `scala-2.10.1`.

Comment: Turns out that it actually works, but my IDE (Intellij) throws false errors. I guess that's what you get when you try to work in fancy IDE's and not the prompt. After checking my version in my prompt I ran the scala file in scalas REPL it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm using IntelliJ I also fell for the false errors. I rewrote your solution a bit, not sure if it's applicable in your case, but I thought I'd post it - maybe it will help. I moved the evaluate functions to the `TypedExpr`:

```
sealed trait TypedExpr[T] {
  def eval: T
}
case class CstI(value: Int) extends TypedExpr[Int] {
  def eval = value
}
case class Add(e1: TypedExpr[Int], e2: TypedExpr[Int]) extends TypedExpr[Int] {
  def eval = e1.eval + e2.eval
}
case class Times(e1: TypedExpr[Int], e2: TypedExpr[Int]) extends TypedExpr[Int] {
  def eval = e1.eval * e2.eval
}
case class LessThanEq(e1: TypedExpr[Int], e2: TypedExpr[Int]) extends TypedExpr[Boolean] {
  def eval = e1.eval <= e2.eval
}
case class IfThenElse[T](cond: TypedExpr[Boolean], e1: TypedExpr[T], e2: TypedExpr[T]) extends TypedExpr[T] {
  def eval = if (cond.eval) e1.eval else e2.eval
}

object Language {
  def eval[T](e: TypedExpr[T]): T = e.eval
}
```

Comment: Appreciated. Certainly helped my understanding of the concept, thumbs up

Comment: No problem, I found that it's more logical to have the evaluate function enclosed in the class that represents what needs to be evaluated. It's easier to reason about and test (and you won't miss a `TypedExpr` implementation without a way to evaluate it).